# Strange encoding of non-ASCII character in URL

Tags: url, character-encoding, urlencode

My mother recently received the following scam message on Whatsapp (I have added multiple extra m's to the end of the link below in case of accidental clicks. Obviously the original link itself ended only with `.com`):

> British Airways is giving free 5000 tickets to celebrate its birthday. Get your free ticket at : [http://www.briṭishairways.commmmmmmm/](http://www.bri%E1%B9%ADishairways.commmmmmmm/)

It seems to be a legitimate link to the British Airways URL, especially since Whatsapp doesn't allow link obfuscation (i.e. sending someone to SO by clicking [http://www.google.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) isn't possible).

However, a careful look will show that the `t` is in fact a `ṭ` ([Latin T with dot below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%AC)). Also, if one either hovers the mouse over the link in Chrome, the URL that appears at the bottom-left corner of the screen is in fact http://www.xn--briishairways-rt1g.commmmmmmm/. This is also the output from doing a right-click > Copy Link Address. (Try it yourself!)

Also, if I edit the body of the link, the `rt1g` part changes, as if it's a counter for where to put the dot. For example:

- briṭishairways = xn--briishairways-rt1g
- briṭishairway = xn--briishairway-vk5f
- riṭishairway = xn--riishairway-yb9e
- rṭishairay = xn--rishairay-5s6d

What's especially odd is that the Wikipedia link I used for [Latin T with dot below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%AC) also uses the same character (well, the capitalized version of it), and the URL shown on mouse-hover does not have this effect. (Try it yourself!)

What is going on here?

Comment: It's the way DNS names with non-ASCII characters are encoded. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: I figured it was something like that, but searching for "xn" and some other keywords on Google gave me nothing. Feel free to write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Try it yourself at https://www.punycoder.com/